# Symfony 2 Doctrine ODM returning errors on existing fields

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simple symfony 2 setup with Doctrine ORM and a db with some underscore seperated field names (for instance "error_page"). Querying this never gives a result (getTitle does give a result, getErrorPage is always empty) and symfony gives me an error:

```
Method "error_page" for object "My\CmsBundle\Document\Website" does not exist in MyCmsBundle:Default:dashboard.html.twig at line 5
```

I can't figure out why... My Document looks like this:

```
<?php

// src/My/CmsBundle/Document/Website.php
namespace My\CmsBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *     collection="websites"
 * )
 */
class Website
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $slug;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="error_page")
     */
    protected $error_page = "";


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $title;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String(name="seo_title")
     */
    protected $seo_title;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $seo_description;




    /**
     * @MongoDB\Collection
     */
    protected $url = array();

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return self
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string $slug
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string $title
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set errorPage
     *
     * @param string $errorPage
     * @return self
     */
    public function setErrorPage($errorPage)
    {
        $this->error_page = $errorPage;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get errorPage
     *
     * @return string $errorPage
     */
    public function getErrorPage()
    {
        return $this->error_page;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param collection $url
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return collection $url
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set seoTitle
     *
     * @param string $seoTitle
     * @return self
     */
    public function setSeoTitle($seoTitle)
    {
        $this->seo_title = $seoTitle;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get seoTitle
     *
     * @return string $seoTitle
     */
    public function getSeoTitle()
    {
        return $this->seo_title;
    }

    /**
     * Set seoDescription
     *
     * @param string $seoDescription
     * @return self
     */
    public function setSeoDescription($seoDescription)
    {
        $this->seo_description = $seoDescription;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get seoDescription
     *
     * @return string $seoDescription
     */
    public function getSeoDescription()
    {
        return $this->seo_description;
    }
}
```

Document creation via this document works fine by the way. The field name is also set to error_page as expected... I'm at a loss here :S

Comment: Use camelCase in Twig: `{{ document.errorPage }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Doctrine+Symfony2 assume camel case variable naming. Twig using the getter method names should be obvious, how should it access protected/private variables? It needs a name for something public : the getter. You're probably wondering why "get" is ignored; it is a simplification for designers as they normally shouldnt know about what "getters" are and the difference between methods and variables.

so in your twig file ,change :

```
{{document.error_page}}
```

to

```
{{document.errorPage}}
```

[this](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#variables) would helpful.

Comment: Works like a charm. The issue with data not showing in the controller was due to caching being too harsh... Thanks!